# "Object required" when using Set in an assignment

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

```
call main()
sub main()
    Dim scmd
    Set scmd = "c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe //nologo c:\s.vbs"
    createobject("wscript.shell").run scmd,0,false
end sub
```

It gives me error:

> `Object required: '[string: "c:\windows\system32\"]' Code 800A01A8`

Comment: Just delete `set` its only for object references not basic variable assignments

Answer (score 15):

> **Update**
>
> As it's not clear feel it best to point out your `Object Required` issue is due to this line
>
> ```vb
> Set scmd = "c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe //nologo c:\s.vbs"
> ```
>
> This is because an Object is expected but you are assigning it a string, by removing the `Set` your code will work (As [Ekkehard.Horner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603855/ekkehard-horner) has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23637797/692942)).
>
> ---
>
> Below is my interpretation of situation. First looking at your code it almost looked like it had mixed the instantiation of the `WScript.Shell` object with the command line for the `.Run()` method. It was my first stab at breaking down the code, rearranging it then putting it back together.

---

**Original Answer**

1. Your `Set scmd` should be instantiating the `WScript.Shell` (As [Ekkehard.Horner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603855/ekkehard-horner) points out you can use `Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run` for a one off reference but I wouldn't recommend it).
2. The `.Run()` should be executed by the instantiated `scmd` object and passed the command line to execute.

Here is an example I've renamed some of the variables (`scmd` to `cmd` for example).

```vb
Call main()

Sub main()
    'Renamed variables to cmd is your object and cmdline is your file path.
    Dim cmd, cmdline
    'Instantiate WshShell object
    Set cmd = Server.Createobject("WScript.Shell")
    'Set cmdline variable to file path
    cmdline = "c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe //nologo c:\s.vbs"
    'Execute Run and return immediately
    Call cmd.Run(cmdline, 0, False)
End Sub
```

---

**Things to consider**

When using WScript.Shell in Classic ASP to run executables there are some things to consider;

1. Run command will execute using the current Application Pool identity.
2. Run will execute the executable on the server not at the client (server side).

Comment: +1 for the greyed part at the top. (BTW: please consider to delete your wrong/misleading remark to Alex K.'s comment above)

Answer (score 0):

As

```
>> WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory
>>
E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\trials\AlgoTaBu\SuSo\wsf
```

proves, there is no rule or law at all that "Your `Set scmd` should be instantiating the WScript.Shell". Putting the command to execute in string variable scmd (or perhaps better sCmd) and not creating a variable for an only-once-used value are good practices.

The revised version (minus the stupid Set):

```
call main()
sub main()
    Dim scmd
    scmd = "c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe //nologo c:\s.vbs"
    createobject("wscript.shell").run scmd,0,false
end sub
```

will work just as well as Lankymart's version.

**To spell everything out:**

1. The Set keyword, its semantic, and its error message are design flaws, that make VBScript harder to use correctly. `"site:stackoverflow.com vbscript "object required" Set"` results in 1500 hits. Even if much of those hits do not concern the `"Set x = 'non-object'` blunder, that's clearly too much. To explain/excuse those IEDs you have to consider that BASIC is a stone age language.
2. A person learning VBScript is entitled to be surprised by the `"Set x = 'non-object'` mistake twice. If it happens trice (or more often), he/she should be ashamed (and keep silent about it). Above all that problem should not pollute this site.
3. When I posted my contribution, all answers/comments - with the exception of Alex K.'s  'Just delete the Set' - emphasized/concentrated on the .Run statement; one answer called the script "topsy curvy", one answer even repeated the atrocity. So I tried to point out that there is exactly **one** error: The spurious Set.
4. I failed miserably. Evidence: John Saunders changed the title from "VBScript error" (unspecific but true) to "“Object required” when calling Run on Wscript.Shell" (specific but wrong), Lankymart engaged in psychological/philological research to save the Set at the expense of the string.
5. My only hope: Everybody reading this will be so disgusted by my harping on the Set, that she/he from now on will think twice when typing:

wtf

```
Set x = "     ---- stop or be damned!!!
Set x = obj.getNumber() + 4  ---- oh no!!!
```

1. All to no avail - [Same mistake again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23645754/603855)

Comment: Just think breaking it down so they can see where the code has screwed up was beneficial. Must admit never used `Server.CreateObject` that way (as a one off object), but don't think I ever will. My point about the `Set` is the OP is trying to `Set` a string which causes the `Object Required`.

Comment: The fact the OP already had a `Set` in there suggests to me that they probably originally had the object being instantiated there but at some point while modify the code they ended up with it topsy turvy.

Comment: To be honest is your answer answering the question or is it just a critique of my answer?

Comment: @Lankymart That's how Ekke rolls, check out this gem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814335/only-making-one-number-instead-of-a-number-between-0-and-2-multiple-times/23814506#23814506 gotta give him credit, he sure likes hearing himself talk.

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure, try change

```
Set scmd = "c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe //nologo c:\s.vbs"
```

to

```
Set scmd = "c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe" //nologo "c:\s.vbs"
```

Comment: `scmd` is a string so `Set` isn't needed. Also any string escaping in [tag:vbscript] or [tag:asp-classic] requires `""` or the string will throw a syntax error. In this example the string should be `scmd = """c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe"" //nologo ""c:\s.vbs"""`. But that is not the issue anyway.

Comment: -1: Not even syntactically correct; using Set in non-object assignments is blatantly wrong.

Comment: -1 Thanks for answering, but we prefer _good_, _correct_ answers. If you're not sure, then don't answer.

Comment: Allright, i wanted to help but just dont answer when i am not sure. I´ll keep it in mind, thanks!