# Only making one number instead of a number between 0 and 2 multiple times

Tags: random, vbscript, numbers, key

Ok, so I was going to make a neat program that made your Number Lock, Caps Lock, and Scroll Lock keys flash. My problem is when I run it, it only produces one number, instead of multiple ones that are different, any ideas as to what the problem might be?

```
Set Keys = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 'So The Script Can Press keys
Dim MAX, MIN 'Declaration
MAX = 2 'Sets MAX Equal To 2
MIN = 0 'Sets MIN Equal To 0
Randomize 'So The Numbers Are Different All The Time

Number = (Int((MAX-MIN+1)*Rnd+MIN)) 'Assigns The Random number To A Variable
Do Until X = 10 'Does The Loop 10 Times
Select Case Number
    Case 0 'If Number = 0 Then The Following happens
        WScript.Sleep 500 'Stops The Script For 500 Milliseconds
        Keys.SendKeys("{NUMLOCK}") 'Pushes The Number Lock
    Case 1 'If Number = 1Then The Following happens
        WScript.Sleep 500 'Stops The Script For 500 Milliseconds
        Keys.SendKeys("{CAPSLOCK}") 'Pushes The Caps Lock
    Case 2 'If Number = 2 Then The Following happens
        WScript.Sleep 500 'Stops The Script For 500 Milliseconds
        Keys.SendKeys("{SCROLLLOCK}") 'Pushes The Scroll Lock
End Select
X = X + 1 'Increment
Loop
```

Comment: Well, for starters, you might want to put your equation within the loop so it regenerates the random number after every loop.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe i missed that. Thanks it is working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting comment as answer...

Well, for starters, you might want to put your equation within the loop so it regenerates the random number after every loop.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create the random number **in** the loop:

```
Do Until X = 10 'Does The Loop 10 Times
  Number = (Int((MAX-MIN+1)*Rnd+MIN)) 'Assigns The Random number To A Variable
  Select Case Number
```

Comment: Really, Ekkehard? Ok. I see how it is. smh.