# MS Access return function to vbs

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, vba

i'm trying to "compile" an Access ADP file to obtain an ADE with a small vbs script.

```
Option Explicit

Const acCmdMakeMDEFile = 603
Const msoAutomationSecurityLow = 1
Dim AccessADP
Set AccessADP = CreateObject("Access.Application")
AccessADP.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
AccessADP.visible=false
AccessADP.OpenCurrentDataBase(SourceOfADP)
```

I need to call one sub and one function which are written inside the ADP...for the sub no problem

```
AccessADP.Run "nameOfTheSub"
```

but i'm not able to use the function (that has to return one numeric value). 
The Access function is very simple

```
public function getValue() as Integer
    getValue=10
end function
```

none of these solutions works for me

```
dim returnValue
set returnValue = AccessADP.Run "getValue"


dim returnValue
returnValue = AccessADP.Run "getValue"
```

any ideas to catch the return value from the function from vbs?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As you want to

1. get the return value of a function
2. expect a non-object return value

use

```
dim returnValue
returnValue = AccessADP.Run("getValue")
```

mark the param list () - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13622374/603855) - and the missing `Set` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23637797/603855).